# mongoProperties properties are null

Tags: jhipster

I'm a newbie to Jhipster. I created gateway project with mongodb. I started jhipster-registry and mongodb in docker. There is no other microservice. when I debugged gateway project, I found below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Database name must not be empty
at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:168)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory.<init>(SimpleMongoDbFactory.java:142)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory.<init>(SimpleMongoDbFactory.java:93)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoConfiguration.mongoDbFactory(AbstractMongoConfiguration.java:114)
at com.xx.cloud.demo.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$65a29278.CGLIB$mongoDbFactory$6(<generated>)
at com.xx.cloud.demo.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$65a29278$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7563f63.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
at com.xx.cloud.demo.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$65a29278.mongoDbFactory(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
... 182 common frames omitted
```

I put a breakpoint within method getDatabaseName() in DatabaseConfiguration.java class and debug getwayApp.java. I found all the properties of mongoProperties are null except url with value 'mongodb://localhost/test'. I configured data in application-dev.yml like this:

```
data:
    cassandra:
        contactPoints: localhost
        protocolVersion: V4
        compression: LZ4
        keyspaceName: gateway
        repositories:
            enabled: false
        mongodb:
         host: localhost
         port: 27017
         uri: mongodb://localhost:27017
         database: jhipsterMongodbSampleApplication
```

but it was the same result of I didn't configure it.

How and where should I configure mongodb in gateway? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the `mongodb` block under `cassandra`, reduce indentation.

Also don't forget that your application properties should be defined in registry for production like deployment.

Comment: Thanks for replying. There is no error association with Mongodb by now. but another error arise.

Comment: 2016-09-03 16:21:27.715  WARN 43029 --- [           main] org.reflections.Reflections              : could not create Dir using commons_vfs2 from url file:/System/Library/Java/Extensions/libJ3DAudio.jnilib. skipping.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/vfs2/VFS
 at org.reflections.vfs.Vfs$DefaultUrlTypes$7.matches(Vfs.java:281)

Comment: You probably need to add a dependency to your pom.xml see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-vfs2/2.0

Comment: If this is not due to some change you made and this fixes the issue, you should report it as a bug on our github project

Comment: Ok thanks for help. I didn't change any code. I will file a CR on your JIRA

Comment: Hi Gaël Marziou
You can follow this example to reproduce another issue at https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/4071
The example is here:
https://simplestepsolutions.wordpress.com/2016/07/27/jhipster-3-5-1-microservices-with-uaa/